# HibernateException No Session found for current thread when calling service from controller but not in my test

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm getting the No session found exception when I launch my application and call service from my controller. However I can successfully call the same service from a unit test.

This is happening when I call the userService.userExists(username) method on the controller class. I started tracing the execution in a debugger and found that the TransactionSynchronizationManager resources object map is empty even though I am decorating the service as transactional. However when I call the service from my unit test, there are resources on the TransactionSynchronizationManager.

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class DiaryController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/diary/{username}")
    public String home(@PathVariable String username, ModelMap model) {
        String authUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();

        if(authUser.equals(username)) {
            model.addAttribute("message", "Hey there. How's it going " + username + "?");
        }
        else if (userService.userExists(username)) {
            model.addAttribute("message", "You're looking at diary for " + username + ".");
        }
        else {
            model.addAttribute("message", "User " + username + " does not exist.");
        }
        return "diary";
    }
}
```

Hibernate context:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:database.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="mappingLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:hbm/User.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>

    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Application context:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
```

UserDoaImpl:

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl extends AbstractDaoImpl<User, String> implements UserDao {

    protected UserDaoImpl() {
        super(User.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveUser(User user) {
        saveOrUpdate(user);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findUsers(String username) {
        return findByCriteria(Restrictions.like("username", username, MatchMode.EXACT));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean exists(String username) {
        return findById(username) != null;
    }
}
```

And my working unit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
        "classpath:/spring/applicationContext.xml",
        "classpath:/spring/securityContext.xml",
        "classpath:/spring/hibernateContext.xml"
})
public class UserServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Test
    public void userServiceTest() {
        Assert.assertTrue(userService.userExists("fergal"));
    }
}
```

UserServiceImpl:

```
@Service("userService")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public User findByUserName(String userName) {
        return userDao.findById(userName);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void saveUser(User user) {
        userDao.saveUser(user);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void deleteUser(String userName) {
        User user = userDao.findById(userName);
        if (user != null) {
            userDao.delete(user);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findUsers(String user) {
        return userDao.findUsers(user);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean userExists(String username) {
        return userDao.exists(username);
    }
```

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>MyApp</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myapp-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myapp-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/spring/**</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Can you please paste the code for `UserService`?

Comment: Can you show your web.xml? Do you divide application context into two xml files(one for services, another for controllers)?  I met this problem ever.

Comment: Added UserServiceImpl and web.xml
I divided the application context into 3 files: applicationContext.xml, hibernateContext.xml and securityContext.xml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following filter to your web.xml. You can check more information about this filter at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html

```
    <filter>
          <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
          <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
          <init-param>
             <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
             <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>         
          </init-param>      
       </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. I just needed to add the mapping for the filter as well. Maybe you can add that to your answer.