# java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManager is closed with HSQL

Tags: java, spring, hsqldb

I am building a simple spring web application for educational purposes and I have a little problem with the persistence level- `java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManager is closed` is thrown when I try to get something from the database. The objects are persisted, but when I get try to make a query that exception is thrown. So I am using Hibernate with HSQL inmemory db and here is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="pp_persistence_unit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testDB"/>
        <property name="sqltool.charset" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
        <property name="show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
        <property name="current_session_context_class" value="thread"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

The stacktrace from the error is the following:

```
 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/web-app] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManager is closed] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManager is closed
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.checkOpen(EntityManagerImpl.java:105)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:491)
at web.task.dao.ConnectionDao.getConnectionsCount(ConnectionDao.java:67)
at web.task.transformation.ConnectionTransformator.getPagesCount(ConnectionTransformator.java:48)
at web.task.business.ConnectionService.getPagesCount(ConnectionService.java:45)
at web.task.controllers.ConnectionController.getAllConnections(ConnectionController.java:71)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Here it ii the getConnectionsCount() method

```
public int getConnectionsCount() {
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select count(c.id) from Connection c");
    return (Integer)query.getSingleResult();
}
```

I really don't know what is the problem. I had an assumption that it could be from the encoding of the database, but I tried to set it to UTF-8, but the error was still the same.

Sorry for forgetting, here is my application-context.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd ">

<context:component-scan base-package="web.task.business">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Service" />
</context:component-scan>

<context:component-scan base-package="web.task.dao">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository" />
</context:component-scan>

<context:component-scan base-package="web.task.transformation">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="web.task.annotations.Transformation" />
</context:component-scan>

<bean id="ppEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="pp_persistence_unit" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="ppEntityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

Comment: Please share your spring context XML

Comment: Sorry, I really forgot- the post is upldated.

Comment: can you post the web.xml please?

Comment: Can you also post your web.task.dao.ConnectionDao.getConnectionsCount method?

Comment: I have no problem to post it, but that exception is thrown whenever I try to get something from the database

Comment: @HristoAngelov check my answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939932/hibernateexception-no-session-found-for-current-thread-when-calling-service-from/15940848#15940848 I think this will solve your problem

Comment: @Hristo Where do your transactions start and end? In the DAO or service tier? How do you inject your entity manager into the DAOs?

Comment: The transaction is opened in the service tier. I inject the persistence manager through its set method with PersistenceContext annotation. The interesting part as I mentioned in my question is that the save of the entity is performed without any errors. The exception which I mentioned is thrown when I try to get something from the db. @fmodos I am using the jpa implementation and I have no hibernate session, so I am not sure if this can help me.

Comment: do u see any other exception when the server starts? I remember seeing this error when I used in-memory database. I'm trying to think how I resolved it.

Comment: Nope, everything is fine at the server start- this is the only exception, which is thrown.

Comment: @HristoAngelov I think I know what is happening, but I can't find it in the xml... so I am assuming that you might have some annotation like transactional in your save method that isn't in the query method.

Comment: All the transactional annotations are in the service tier as I mentioned, so I don't think that is the issue